# Restrict users to enter special characters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to use this regex `/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/` for restricting special character in views itself

`<%= text_field_tag :realname, params[:realname], :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Realname", id: "Text--AreaFocus" , pattern: "/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/" %>`

I tried this above code but it doesn't seem working. Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: I think my this code itself is no working <%= text_field_tag :realname, params[:realname], :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Realname", id: "Text--AreaFocus" %>

Comment: Regex is working pattern checking is not working.

Comment: `<%= text_field_tag :realname, params[:realname], pattern: "/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/", :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Realname", id: "Text--AreaFocus" %>`

Comment: Thanks @ashwinkumar it works but i think my pattern itself is wrong to restrict special characters :P But anyways thanks

Comment: @ShilpiAgrawal , for server side validation you can add match in model

Comment: Yes @VishnuAtrai i did that only but i want for client side.

Comment: are you looking for any function from js to validate or something from rails inbuilt methods

Comment: rails inbuilt methods i got it working with @ashwinkumar 's comment.

Comment: If you work with jquery validation(custom validation) match method, It is working.

Comment: @stribizhev i gave same thing in pattern but its not taking my input even just containing numbers.

Comment: Try removing `"` symbols from around the pattern: `<%= text_field_tag :realname, params[:realname], pattern: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*\z/, :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Realname", id: "Text--AreaFocus" %>`

Comment: Did you finally solve the issue? Sorry, but I am curious.

Comment: That's okay. I forgot to mention. I found the another way to do it in JS itself but at the end i had to use reggae only and the reggae was correct so it worked. Thanks a lot :) .

Comment: Sorry, you did not put my hashtag into the comment, I only found it today: does it mean I can post my solution so that you could accept it?

Comment: @stribizhev yeah sure :)

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the class as `"form-control"` and remove the double quotes from around the regex that you declare using a literal:

```
<%= text_field_tag :realname, params[:realname], pattern: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*\z/, :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Realname", id: "Text--AreaFocus" %>
                                                         ^                   ^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, since it is RoR, to match the start and end of string, you should use `\A` and `\z` anchors instead of `^`/`$`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of) an help you?

So put something like this in your model:

```
validates_format_of :realname, :with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do `pattern` recognition with html tag.

```
<%= text_field_tag :realname, params[:realname], pattern: "/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/", :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Realname", id: "Text--AreaFocus" %>
```

Also I recommend you write validation in `Model`.